# How can I write redirect rule to prevent duplicate content from comment page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Please, how can I use redirect each of the following (using htaccess):

```
http://www.example.com/jane-doe-online-5026?comments=true
http://www.example.com/jane-doe-online-5026?postcomment=true
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/jane-doe-online-5026
```

Note: It's a Wordpress blog and the duplicates are showing on Google Webmaster tools - under HTML suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(post)?comment(s)?=true$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}? [L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I'll try that and see how it goes - will also report back if it works or not.

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you. When you get a chance please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the tick below the answer).